How do I create a managed attribute compatible with Pydantic?
I have a model where I need to do some work any time a value is set. Typically I'd use a managed property. However, I want to validate the new value (using Pydantic) whenever it is set still. I've tried using @validate_call, but it does not raise expected ValidationErrors for bad inputs. Mock code below.
from pydantic import BaseModel, validate_call

P = TypeVar("P", covariant=True)

class ManagedNode(BaseModel, Generic[P]):
    _parent: Optional[weakref.ref] = None

    @property
    def parent(self) -> Optional[P]:
        return self._parent() if self._parent is not None else None

    @parent.setter
    @validate_call
    def parent(self, parent: P):  # type: ignore
        self._parent = weakref.ref(parent) if parent is not None else None


class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

ManagedNode[A]().parent = B()  # this does not raise a ValidationError

Is there a better approach to managed attributes with Pydantic?
Using Pydantic V2 (2.9.2)
(Note there is a separate issue related to P being covariant and used as a method parameter, hence the # type: ignore)

I don't think that validate_call is designed to handle generic types that way. The decorator has no chance to determine the type of P at class creation 'cause in general the concrete type will be defined later on e.g. inside a subclass. Unfortunately, I don't think pydantic really supports this pattern yet.
The (probably) easiest workaround would be to use regular attributes, override the __setattr__ method and only do extra stuff if it's "your" field. That's a bit dirty, I know.
If you want to do it more properly you'd have to hook into the class creation somewhere to rebuild the methods and setting an explicit annotation into the methods dynamically. Then you could throw it into the validate_call decorator again which should then be able to create a proper validation schema for it. I believe, the important stuff happens somewhere in the metaclass ModelMetaclass. But that's surely not easy to do.

You declared _parent using type weakref.ref[Any]. It needs to be weakref.ref[P] instead.
class ManagedNode(BaseModel, Generic[P]):
    _parent: Optional[weakref.ref[P]] = None

    ...

